# Least square proof, Notation sum matrices

Tags: matrices, summation, matrix-equations

I have spent weeks trying to understand a "proof" in my textbook. However I am not able to get what is going on.

The "proof" goes like this:(I have marked the numbers in red)

[image: Proof]

This is how I have done the calculations which might be all wrong and hopefully is since I dont end up with getting the result as equ. 4(marked in red)

[image: a1]
[image: a2]

My problem as you can see is that I get different answer, from equation 4(in red) which states that the matrix multiplication with sum and plain matrix multiplication should provide the same answer-->(be equal to each-other)

In other words, equation 7 and the last matrix calculated( equation 11+ equation 12) are not equal to to each other. Can someone show me what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $x_i$ are the transposed of the row-vectors of $X$, or, equivalently, the column-vectors of $X^T$. You chose the column-vectors of $X$ instead.

So in your example: $x_1 = (2,1)'$,$x_2 = (3,1)'$,$x_3 = (4,1)'$ and $$x_1x_1^T = \left(\begin{matrix} 4 & 2 \\ 2 & 1 \end{matrix} \right)$$
and so on and their sum indeed coincides with $X^TX$.

Comment: Yeas why cant I see this straight away!. btw I think you need a edit on the last( think its a typo) (4,1)' should be x3 or am I wrong?

Comment: That's right, thank you.

Comment: Could you explain quickly how you saw straight away that xi were transpose of row vector of X. I just need to see the logic so I dont end up doing the same mistake again.

Comment: Sure: have a closer look at the entries of $X$ in 3). The first row has the entries of the vector $x_1$. But as $x_1$ is a column-vector, we have to transpose the row to get the right dimensions. That also works as a general principle: the first thing we should check when identifying vectors is dimension, as you had a dimension mismatch between the two matrices that are supposed to coincide.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am 1 week into my first course of matrices and would not have been able to see this if it was not for your help.